File preview over popup
i have a popup, which contains some information and file preview button,
How to preview the file, as we are already inside a popup

What kind of file? Is it not possible to display the preview directly in the popup? What kind of information is in the popup?

There are 2 ways of achieving this that I can think of.

Open a new non modal window that does not affect/block the flow of the user. The preview is just a preview with no actions.

Non modal https://www.nngroup.com/articles/modal-nonmodal-dialog/

Temporarily close the current pop up from the place that user has clicked preview and instead of closing the preview, you need to have a back button that user can understand that it is going to take user back to the pop up !

Hey, Also, post whatever you decide next.
